# Working example Coldfusion and Linkedin API

Tags: api, coldfusion, linkedin-api

Has anyone managed to get the LinkedIn API working from within a coldfusion application?
There are some threads in the Linkedin Developer's community, but any actual working examples or complete code are missing.

In the end I'm looking for a solution to import LinkedIn profiles to our recruitment solution - and also fetch updated profiles regularly - ofcourse after the user gives us access to his/her profile.

Any help appreciated, especially with some kind of working setup (even if only basic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ColdFusion can create and use Java objects, the easiest solution is to use a Java API to access LinkedIn. One option is [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/).

## Update

I haven't found any evidence of a CF-based wrapper so unfortunately you're going to have to figure this part out.

You don't need to really know how Java works to use Java objects in ColdFusion; you just have to know what the classes are in the API in question and then create the necessary objects and then call the relevant functions. I assume linkedin-j offers some kind of .jar file. You need to add that to your classpath; there are plenty of resources on line on [how to do this](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/the_definitive.html) (if that link breaks, just search for `coldfusion jar classpath`). Then, figure out which object you need, create an instance of that object you need using `CreateObject`.

The [getting started page](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/GettingStarted) talks about a `LinkedInApiClientFactory` object. You'd create this in ColdFusion by doing something like

```
<cfset factory = CreateObject('com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient').newInstance(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue)>
<cfset client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessTokenValue, tokenSecretValue)>
```

At which point you can use all of the functions available to the LinkedInApiClient, such as `getProfileByUrl`.

Use the documentation available at the linkedin-j site to find out about the functions you can call on the LinkedInApiClient, and work from there.

Comment: yes - true; i found the link to the java lib; only problem i face is that i'm not a java-guy and i cant really find any good information about where to start and how to integrate within CF. 
Do you have any experience with this library and the connection with CF?

Comment: I didn't get a message about your update..:-) I will dive into this and maybe add some insights afterwards. thanks!