# cfhttp how to not encode plus sign

Tags: coldfusion, linkedin-api, cfhttp

Situation: I am trying to call the LinkedIn API from a ColdFusion CFC to get the user's profile and network (connections).  The LinkedIn API states that to do this you must call a URL with scope=r_fullprofile+r_network.

Issue: ColdFusion is automatically encoding the URL, so the plus sign is getting encoded, and LinkedIn is rejecting my call.  Is there any way around this?  I've posted a link below to some code snippets on github which I believe illustrate the issue.

https://gist.github.com/4535364

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope field is a space delimited list.

The `+` character is commonly used as a shortcut for space, since it's more readable than `%20` (which is what space encodes to).

If using a plus character results in an encoded plus (%2B) being sent, then you are left with two other ways of putting the space into the URL:

1. using a literal space character, or
2. using an encoded space `%20`

Try both of those options, ideally using a network snifer (e.g. [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/)) so that you can see accurately what is being sent.

Update: As per comments below, `%20` is correct, but the signature based string needs to be encoded again, so for that the `%` becomes `%25`, giving a result of `%2520`.

Comment: Hi, Peter, thanks for your reply, but a literal space does not work either.

Comment: Hmm, I was basing that of some examples I saw (since trying to visit the LinkedIn API itself was  giving 404s or redirecting to home page). Is there a specific LinkedIn page where this is documented?

Comment: @PeterBoughton I found this post while searching that discusses the encoding needed.  [Permission scope in request token query not working](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/permission-scope-request-token-query-not-working) See the number 6 response by Jack Newcombe. By they way, I am also having issues getting to that linkedin page.  It's sloooowwww.

Comment: If I change the URL to HTTPS it works, otherwise the subdomain reverts to `www.` :/  

Anyhow, that seems to confirm that `+` and `%20` should work.

wellercs - have you tried %20 yet?

Comment: @Miguel-F - thanks for the link, I'll play around with the scenarios in #6

Comment: So, am I right in thinking that if you replace the nasty + sign in the URL with %2B, the LinkedIn API still doesn't like it?

Comment: @Miguel-F - the link you provided has the solution (#35) so thanks again for that!

Comment: @PeterBoughton the issue was a two-part issue. the post parameters needed to encode the + as %20 as you suggested but the signature based string needed to encode it as %2520 so I apologize since you were correct but I didn't know that the signature string needed to be %2520 (I was using %20 for the signature string as well)

Comment: @MattGifford %2B was not the correct encoding since it needed to be the encoding for a space instead of a plus sign. I originally thought it needed to be for the plus sign but it ended up being for the space and actually needed to be 2 different encodings for the space (see my above comment). Thanks for your comment though!

Answer (score 2):

I have searched around on this for a bit and I am seeing lots of examples where ColdFusion is not playing nicely with the LinkedIn API. So I'm afraid if you do get passed this issue (although I have not come up with an alternative yet) another will crop up.  While searching I found several suggestions from people to use the [linkedin-j, A Java wrapper for LinkedIn APIs](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) instead.  Here are some of the references that I found:

[Working example Coldfusion and Linkedin API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165443/working-example-coldfusion-and-linkedin-api)

[LinkedIn-J does not return educations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916711/linkedin-j-does-not-return-educations)

[401 Unauthorized response. API people/~ and people/id=; ColdFusion, cfhttp](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2233)

[Problem updating status - 401 unauthorized - ColdFusion](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1551)

[linkedin-j Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/GettingStarted)

**Side Note** Your github code example is making a `cfhttp` call to 'receiver.cfm' but you called the file 'cfhttp_receiver.cfm'.  In this line:

```
<cfhttp url="http://#cgi.http_host#/sandbox/receiver.cfm?scope=#url.scope#" method="post" resolveurl="no">
```

Comment: Using a tested wrapper is a sensible approach, but since the API is just OAuth+REST there's no reason why CF shouldn't work with it? :/

Comment: @PeterBoughton I totally agree with you Peter. Assuming that the requested URL will work with the '+' sign intact then it is just a matter of ColdFusion not encoding that character.  But how to do that is a mystery...?

Comment: @Miguel-F yes, I uploaded the code with a different name and forgot to change my link in the code sample. it was meant for a simple example. I am using a [LinkedIn CFC](http://linkedin.riaforge.org/) I found which I have made some modifcations to get some other things working. I really want to avoid linkedin-j but thanks for the suggestion and links.